# Is sending error report from PHP Exception __destruct() method a Good or Bad Idea?

Tags: php, exception, destructor

I am designing an error handling system for my application. 
I want to base it on exceptions, and I want to get notified by email about every exception which I had not expected.

I thought of a class:

```
class My_Exception extends Exception {

    private $sendErrorReport = true;

    public function __destruct() {
        if ($this->sendErrorReport) {
              // send the error report by email
        }            
    }

    public function cancelErrorReport() {
        $this->sendErrorReport = false;
    }

}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
try { 
   do_something_that_can_throw_exception();
catch (My_Exception $e) {
   if ($e->getCode() == I_KNOW_WHAT_TO_DO ) {
        react_to_exception();
        $e->cancelErrorReport();   
   } else {
        show_error_message($e->getMessage());
   }
}
```

So, basically, when exception happens, and the system kows what to do, it does not bother me as a developer. But when there is something the system can't handle, then I am notified.
I do not want to place the code that notifies me in the catch clause, cause I'm sure I WILL forget it somewhere...

Can I be sure that the exception __destuct method will be called?

Is the __destruct method of exception a good way to achieve this goal?

Is there a better way I could achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a good idea.

Your best option is to replace the unhandled exception handler. See [`set_exception_handler`.](http://php.net/set_exception_handler)
If you catch an exception and then change your mind and want to leave the exception to the exception handler (like you do in your example, upon analyzing the error code), you can always re-throw the exception. Of course, a better option would be to subclass the exception instead of relying on the error code.

Comment: Thank you. The set_exception_handler is unfortunatelly not an option, as the application is already set up and running, and someone before me commited a desing mistake, and each exception is catched and the message is always shown to the user, and nether gets to set_exception_handler. The bad thing is, that each Controller have its own catch code, so I can't put error reporting code there easily. The subclass might be a way to go. I'll think about it. But it also has the disadvantage, that I have to decide to send or not to send error report where I thorw exception, not where I catch it.

Comment: @SWilk I don't understand how your solution applies then. You already have to change all the catch's so that the error report is canceled/not canceled and you have to change the exception hierarchy, which may not even be possible if built-in exception types are used, like `Exception`, `RuntimeException`, etc.

Comment: Good point about build in exceptions. As for changing "all the caches" it is not that bad, as there is very little places where I would wnat to cancel error reports. But You are right. I need to rethink this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply add a method to the Exception class to send an email when it's called?
Something like:

```
class My_Exception extends Exception {

    private $sendErrorReport = true;

    public function __destruct() {
        if ($this->sendErrorReport) {
              // send the error report by email
        }            
    }

    public function cancelErrorReport() {
        $this->sendErrorReport = false;
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        mail(....., $this->getMessage());
    }

}
```

and then you do something like:

```
try { 
   do_something_that_can_throw_exception();
catch (My_Exception $e) {
   if ($e->getCode() == I_KNOW_WHAT_TO_DO ) {
        react_to_exception();
        $e->cancelErrorReport();   
   } else {
        $e->sendEmail();
   }
}
```

Comment: I think I would forget about calling sendEmail() method in some places. Or some new person in company would.